# How can I read newly appended lines from a LARGE (4GB+) open file?

Tags: php

Using PHP 7.3, I'm trying to achieve "tail -f" functionality: open a file, waiting for some other process to write to it, then read those new lines.

Unfortunately, it seems that fgets() caches the EOF condition. Even when there's new data available (filemtime changes), fgets() returns a blank line.

The important part: **I cannot simply close, reopen, then seek, because the file size is tens of gigs in size, well above the 32 bit limit.** The file must stay open in order to be able to read new data from the correct position.

I've attached some code to demonstrate the problem. If you append data to the input file, filemtime() detects the change, but fgets() reads nothing new.

fread() *does* seem to work, picking up the new data but I'd rather not have to come up with a roll-your-own "read a line" solution.

Does anyone know how I might be able to poke fgets() into realising that it's not the EOF?

```
$fn = $argv[1];

$fp = fopen($fn, "r");
fseek($fp, -1000, SEEK_END);
$filemtime = 0;
while (1) {
  if (feof($fp)) {
    echo "got EOF\n";
    sleep(1);
    clearstatcache();
    $tmp = filemtime($fn);
    if ($tmp != $filemtime) {
      echo "time $filemtime -> $tmp\n";
      $filemtime = $tmp;
    }
  }
  $l = trim(fgets($fp, 8192));
  echo "l=$l\n";
}
```

---

Update: I tried excluding the call to feof (thinking that may be where the state becomes cached) but the behaviour doesn't change; once fgets reaches the original file pointer position, any further fgets reads will return false, even if more data is subsequently appended.

---

Update 2: I ended up rolling my own function that will continue returning new data after the first EOF is reached (in fact, it has no concept of EOF, just data available / data not available). Code not heavily tested, so use at your own risk. Hope this helps someone else.

*** NOTE this code was updated 20th June 2021 to fix an off-by-one error. The comment "includes line separator" was incorrect up to this point.

```
define('FGETS_TAIL_CHUNK_SIZE', 4096);
define('FGETS_TAIL_SANITY', 65536);
define('FGETS_TAIL_LINE_SEPARATOR', 10);

function fgets_tail($fp) {

// Get complete line from open file which may have additional data written to it.
// Returns string (including line separator) or FALSE if there is no line available (buffer does not have complete line, or is empty because of EOF)

  global $fgets_tail_buf;

  if (!isset($fgets_tail_buf))  $fgets_tail_buf = "";

  if (strlen($fgets_tail_buf) < FGETS_TAIL_CHUNK_SIZE) { // buffer not full, attempt to append data to it
    $t = fread($fp, FGETS_TAIL_CHUNK_SIZE);
    if ($t != false)  $fgets_tail_buf .= $t;
  }
  $ptr = strpos($fgets_tail_buf, chr(FGETS_TAIL_LINE_SEPARATOR));
  if ($ptr !== false) {
    $rv = substr($fgets_tail_buf, 0, $ptr + 1);                 // includes line separator
    $fgets_tail_buf = substr($fgets_tail_buf, $ptr + 1);    // may reduce buffer to empty
    return($rv);
  } else {
    if (strlen($fgets_tail_buf) < FGETS_TAIL_SANITY) { // line separator not found, try to append some more data
      $t = fread($fp, FGETS_TAIL_CHUNK_SIZE);
      if ($t != false)  $fgets_tail_buf .= $t;
    }
  }
  return(false);
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: How to read a file live that is constantly being written to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3218895/php-how-to-read-a-file-live-that-is-constantly-being-written-to)

Comment: The solutions in the other question will fail with a file size larger than 32 bits; ftell() will break. That's the difference here.

Comment: You need to clear your static cache or disable your static cache. Also why the hell do you have a singe file that's tens of gigs in size, that's a major hassle for most file readers to open?!

Comment: If you mean clearstatcache(), that doesn't make any difference - it's already in the code above that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: Have you looked at stream_get_contents : https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-get-contents.php

Comment: @Spirit That function allows an offset, but again, I may run into problems if it's limited to 32 bits. (It's functionally equivalent to fseek+fread). The main issue is that PHP signals EOF once and does not seem to update that status, regardless of new data being appended.

Answer (score 0):

The author found the solution himself how to create PHP tail viewer for gians log files 4+ Gb in size.
To mark this question as replied, I summary the solution:

```
define('FGETS_TAIL_CHUNK_SIZE', 4096);
define('FGETS_TAIL_SANITY', 65536);
define('FGETS_TAIL_LINE_SEPARATOR', 10);

function fgets_tail($fp) {

// Get complete line from open file which may have additional data written to it.
// Returns string (including line separator) or FALSE if there is no line available (buffer does not have complete line, or is empty because of EOF)

  global $fgets_tail_buf;

  if (!isset($fgets_tail_buf))  $fgets_tail_buf = "";

  if (strlen($fgets_tail_buf) < FGETS_TAIL_CHUNK_SIZE) { // buffer not full, attempt to append data to it
    $t = fread($fp, FGETS_TAIL_CHUNK_SIZE);
    if ($t != false)  $fgets_tail_buf .= $t;
  }
  $ptr = strpos($fgets_tail_buf, chr(FGETS_TAIL_LINE_SEPARATOR));
  if ($ptr !== false) {
    $rv = substr($fgets_tail_buf, 0, $ptr + 1);                 // includes line separator
    $fgets_tail_buf = substr($fgets_tail_buf, $ptr + 1);    // may reduce buffer to empty
    return($rv);
  } else {
    if (strlen($fgets_tail_buf) < FGETS_TAIL_SANITY) { // line separator not found, try to append some more data
      $t = fread($fp, FGETS_TAIL_CHUNK_SIZE);
      if ($t != false)  $fgets_tail_buf .= $t;
    }
  }
  return(false);
}
```