# PHP - ShellExec screen execution not working

Tags: php, linux, shell-exec, gnu-screen

Im making a webscript starting a minecraft server and i have a problem with shell_exec executing command on screen:

```
$output = shell_exec('screen -d -m -S ServerOne');    
$output2 = shell_exec('screen -S ServerOne -p 0 -X stuff "cd /var/www/html/servers/asd/ && java -Xmx1024M -Xms1024M -jar server.jar nogui > /screenlog ^M"');
```

It creates a screen with name ServerOne but didnt happened nothing after it!
I want to execute on it:

```
cd /var/www/html/servers/asd/ && java -Xmx1024M -Xms1024M -jar server.jar nogui > /screenlog ^M
```

I tried a lot of things and nothing worked, please help! :)

Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Can't you juste make a shell script launching those two commands ?

Comment: I want to make a controll panel for my server(webpage).

Comment: You'd be better off just reading the content of `screenlog` as a stream (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3218895/php-how-to-read-a-file-live-that-is-constantly-being-written-to) that way you'll be monitoring without risk of crashing the minecraft server because of a php error.

Comment: But the server didnt start and i dont see any errors.